Convert from Appium driver to flutter driver on a flutter based app automated using Appium framework
The test cases takes more time to identify an element when using xpath. Also the xpath of an element will change on every new app builds. It causes may test failures. I want to use flutter driver so that, while inspecting the app using the UIAutomator, I can get the element ids or keys which are passed from the flutter side, which are now not showing because of the Appium driver.
I'm automating a flutter based app using Appium, and right now using the AppiumDriver as an interface to the flutter app. I want to switch this to flutter driver to interact more accurate with the flutter app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
